# Rem Font Size Too Small in Safari Desktop

Tags: css, safari, font-size

Safari 6 (desktop) is rendering all of my fonts at a smaller size than what I'm assigning in my stylesheets.

The (mis)calculation is always proportional and affects every font on my site. Fonts that should be 18px are 16px, 28px is calculated as 25px, 24px is appearing as 21px, etc.

I'm using the [62.5% font-sizing technique](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/font-size-with-rem) with rems:

```
html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
  font: normal normal 400 18px/1 sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 28px; // renders at 28px if the next line is disabled
  font-size: 2.8rem; // renders at 25px
}
```

Web Inspector shows that all of my font-size rules are being enforced:

[image]

But for the same body element, it is showing a calculated font size of 16px:

[image]

- No other browsers are doing this, including Mobile Safari on iOS 7.
- If I disable the `rem` font-size rule in Web Inspector, fonts display as they should.
- I thought it might be related to my use of the shorthand rule on the body element, but switching to long-form has no effect.
- I checked other sites (besides my own) to make sure it wasn't a browser setting I wasn't aware of, and it's occurring on both local development sites and in live production.

Has anyone else run into this or can anyone see why this might be occurring?

Comment: I'm running Safari 6.1.3 on OS X 10.7.5 and `body` is showing at 1.8rem (computed 18px) and `h1`s at 2.8rem (computed 28px): http://fiddle.jshell.net/5MfEL/show/ same with Safari 5.1.7/Windows 7 are you sure there isn't some other rule you have that is overriding this? **UPDATE:** are you using `//` as your comments? That's invalid in vanilla CSS. The only type of comment in CSS is `/* comment */` When I copied your code directly, the `rem` rule was being ignored because of the invalid comment preceding it.

Comment: Thanks very much for creating the fiddle and testing this out. I'm experiencing the same issue on the fiddle as I am in my websites. Since you're not getting the same result, it must be something specific to my browser. I'll go digging into the preferences/settings to figure out what I did. Thanks again

Comment: BTW it wasn't the comments, I'm just used to writing SCSS-style comments when I code and didn't think of that when typing my question.